# Ubuntu Won't boot after Bootcamp Expansion

Tags: dual-boot, wubi, mac, bootcamp

I have installed Windows 7 on a Bootcamp Partition, I had only 50 GB assigned to the partition but recently I expanded it with Camptune X, after finishing the expansion nor Windows nor Ubuntu wouldn't load , I fixed the windows loading by running the repair boot command from the Windows 7 installation disk , now Windows boots perfectly, but when choosing Ubuntu OS from the list of OS's I get the message

**Cannot find GRLDR in all devices**  , I've done a lot of research about it and still **haven't found a solution**, I've tried **BootRepair CD** , **Automatically Boot Solving from Windows** (It doesn't even detect theres another OS) , **copying from the Ubuntu's C:/ folder the "WUBILDR." files and pasting them on the main C:/** disk, nothing has worked yet..

So if anyone could lend me a hand over here would be amazing!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looking for the `wubildr` file. It has to be in the root of one of the drives (usually `C:` but can be any): i.e. `C:\wubildr` or `D:\wubildr` etc.

Comment: Hmm how odd, It was looking for it on another partition. Thanks!